# Shell command to find and file the last modified file in a certain directory

Tags: scripting, unix-shell

I want to create an alias that displays the latest log in a certain directory - something like:
`ls -lat *log* | tail -1 | less`

The above command does not work as the output of the `ls -lat` command does not produce a single final name but a full list of columns.

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `-l` and use `-1` instead. Really, it's all [in the book](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls).

Comment: `ls -1at` is more like it, as Ignacio says, but you probably want to use `head -1` instead of tail if I understood 'latest' correctly.

You can otherwise use `ls -1atr | tail -1`, but the first option is better for long directories.

Comment: @Eduardo: Thanks for the comment - Are you sure that `ls -1at` will be faster than `ls -1atr` ? Won't it take the same amount of resources from the system?

Comment: @RonK: -t says sort my modification time, -r says reverse the sort order so -1atr does sort and reverse.

Comment: Also head only processes the first line, tail must process the whole stream and discard everything except the last line - they are very optimized so I may be splitting hairs though : )

Comment: I checked and on a somewhat long dir piping to `head -1` cuts time (real) on half as opposed to piping to tail or doing no pipes at all. It's a bad benchmark but I'm semi-convinced. Also `ls -1atr` and `ls -1at` take the same amount of time, perhaps the sort condition is reversed instead of sorting and then reversing - which makes sense of course.